# Massive time lag between call to startActivity and start of onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera2

I'm having an issue with time lag between the call to startActivity() and the very first instruction of the onCreate() method of the activity that is being started. I've actually added code to measure that time and it averages above 20 seconds.

Here is the significant code from the original activity, called CameraActivity:

```
companion object{
    lateinit var time1 : ZonedDateTime
    lateinit var time2 : ZonedDateTime
    lateinit var time3 : ZonedDateTime
    ...
}
...
private fun takePicture(){

    waitDialog = MyDialogFragment(getString(R.string.wait),false,this)
    waitDialog.show(supportFragmentManager,"") //why isn't the dialog showing???
    try {
        time1 = ZonedDateTime.now()
        val cellGrid = ImageProcessing.getCellGrid(currentImage)
        val puzzle = Puzzle(MLUtilities.predictPuzzle(cellGrid))
        val intent = Intent(thisActivity, GameActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("case", Case.CAMERA.toString())
        intent.putExtra("stage", Stage.INPUT.toString())
        repeat(9) { i ->
            repeat(9) { j ->
                intent.putExtra("value$i$j",puzzle.get(i, j))
            }
        }
        time2 = ZonedDateTime.now()
        thisActivity.startActivity(intent)

    }catch(e: Exception){
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG,"",e)
        waitDialog.dismiss()
    }
    finally {
        waitDialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the activity that is being called:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    CameraActivity.time3 = ZonedDateTime.now()
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"This is how long it takes to recognize the puzzle and load it into intent (in seconds): "+((CameraActivity.time2.toInstant().toEpochMilli()-CameraActivity.time1.toInstant().toEpochMilli()).toDouble()/1000).toString())
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"This is how long it is taking between the startActivity method being called and")
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"the onCreate finally launching (in seconds): "+((CameraActivity.time3.toInstant().toEpochMilli()-CameraActivity.time2.toInstant().toEpochMilli()).toDouble()/1000).toString())
...
}
```

I ran this code six times and used it to record significant durations in the log (removed the parts that would make it harder to read):

```
This is how long it takes to recognize the puzzle and load it into intent (in seconds): 2.189
This is how long it is taking between the startActivity method being called and
the onCreate finally launching (in seconds): 37.806

This is how long it takes to recognize the puzzle and load it into intent (in seconds): 2.099
This is how long it is taking between the startActivity method being called and
the onCreate finally launching (in seconds): 20.074

This is how long it takes to recognize the puzzle and load it into intent (in seconds): 2.123
This is how long it is taking between the startActivity method being called and
the onCreate finally launching (in seconds): 53.911

This is how long it takes to recognize the puzzle and load it into intent (in seconds): 0.69
This is how long it is taking between the startActivity method being called and
the onCreate finally launching (in seconds): 19.981

This is how long it takes to recognize the puzzle and load it into intent (in seconds): 0.843
This is how long it is taking between the startActivity method being called and
the onCreate finally launching (in seconds): 5.461

This is how long it takes to recognize the puzzle and load it into intent (in seconds): 1.014
This is how long it is taking between the startActivity method being called and
the onCreate finally launching (in seconds): 19.813
```

Another issue, which seems tied to it (though it could be separate) is that waitDialog isn't showing up. It was intended as a message that makes it clear the captured image is being processed while the user waits.

I'd really appreciate any help to get this working as it's making the features I've worked hardest on seem like they are lagging when they are actually not. It's ruining an otherwise perfectly functioning game and I have no idea why it's happening.

It's worth mentioning, though I don't think that's the origin of the issue, that CameraActivity is a Views Camera2 API Activity while GameActivity is a Compose-based activity.

Comment: The reason the dialog doesn’t show is that you dismiss it before the function returns. The way the UI works is that the main thread finishes everything in its queue and then it redraws the screen. But everything you’re doing is synchronously done in one function so the main thread has never had a chance to update Ui views and redraw until after all your stuff is done.

Comment: What is the type of the extras you’re putting in the intent? Two seconds is surprisingly a lot for only 81 items. But the long gap between time2 and time3 is likely due to the time it takes to instantiate the second activity and call its first lifecycle functions up to onCreate. So we’d have to see all of that to guess about it.

Comment: Just saw in your comment below that the extras are integers. If that’s the case two seconds is shockingly long to add them to the bundle. What is going on inside Puzzle.get()?

Comment: The two lines responsible for the 2 seconds are: val cellGrid = ImageProcessing.getCellGrid(currentImage)
        val puzzle = Puzzle(MLUtilities.predictPuzzle(cellGrid)) - Image processing mainly

Comment: Pretty much 81 calls to createBitmap to crop and createScaledBitmap to resize. And there are no lifecycle methods before onCreate that I know of.

Comment: There might be a way to optimize how you're doing that, but that would be a separate question. It's risky to put blocking actions like that on the main thread because it freezes the UI and puts your app at risk of an ANR crash. But the slow-opening activity is the more serious issue.

Comment: I think you're right that onCreate is the first possible lifecycle function. But anything you do in the property declarations and `init` blocks happens before `onCreate()`. If you are doing heavy image manipulations or something similar to what you're doing with resizing bitmaps to get those integers for your bundle, that could explain it. If that's the case, the proper way to handle it would be to show a blank screen or some simple loading indicator when the Activity is first created, then launch a coroutine or Future to do the heavy work. This will avoid freezing the UI and the risk of ANR.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you are putting 81 extra values into the Bundle for the intent.

```
repeat(9) { i ->
            repeat(9) { j ->
                intent.putExtra("value$i$j",puzzle.get(i, j))
            }
        }
```

You could just put one object in.
You could do this numerous ways, I just picked this way as I don't know your puzzle domain data:

```
val values = mutableHashMap<String, Int>()
repeat(9) { i ->
            repeat(9) { j ->
                values["value$i$j"] = puzzle.get(i, j)
            }
          }
intent.putExtra("puzzleValues", MyPuzzleValues(values))



@Parcelize
data class MyPuzzleValues(values : HashMap<String, Int>)
```

And you get it out the other side like:

```
data = intent?.getParcelableExtra<MyPuzzleValues>("puzzleValues")
```

---

(You could prove this theory by just commenting out the `putExtra`'s in your code and run your logging again.)

Comment: That isn't the main issue here. Not only is that part of the ocde working fine in multiple other instances through the app, but as you may have noticed, I verified it further by measuring the time it takes to complete the whole processing steps and the intent creation, which is why I'm completely stumped.

Comment: I do understand that the part you pointed out could be improved by the way, it's just that a few dozen integers couldn't possibly make any modern phone processor lag for 54 seconds  before loading an activity, so there is clearly a larger issue here.

Comment: Any idea why the waitDialog isn't showing up?

Comment: I didn't say it was the time it takes to create the intent. I was guestimating it was the time it takes for the system activity to process your intent when it starts up. Did you remove the intent extras and prove it isn't the system bundle handling?

Comment: Yes I verified (although I didn't need to, the exact same code was somewhere else and worked fine). Anyway, it wasn't a total loss as it prompted me to optimize my process more by using one call to 'toString' rather than 81 calls to 'get', and implement one method for it to call since I had the same code written in multiple parts of the app. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple coroutine didn't solve the issue, so I ended up implementing a JobIntentService and an intermediate activity to handle the waiting period. This has solved the problem.

A big thank you to everyone who helped.

Comment: TLDR for future readers & to be clear, the slow down was in the code you didn't show us in the activity `init` before the `onCreate` :-)

Comment: There was no init to show you. I was hoping I woudln't have to address this part because I don't understand it fully, but here it goes: It was in the onPause of the CameraActivity. I still don't know exactly why the camera background thread was lagging when closing in this particular instance, but I didn't actually realize that until I decided to implement the intermediate activity and while it didn't solve the issue on its own, it allowed me to verify that the lag was happening before it, not after it, which pointed me towards CameraActivity.

Comment: I think you were also right when you suspected the intent though because once I delegated the heavy work to the JobIntentService, the lag disappeared completely. I don't know how information passes behind the scenes and why the background thread wasn't quitting in rleation to the intent, but I'm glad I'm rid of the issue.